# Fixed menu not scrolling horizontally

Tags: css, layout, scroll, css-position

I've got a fixed menu - http://mylandscapes.splintderteal.com/

menu isn't scrolling horizontally - problem occurs when page is zoomed in or viewed on a mobile

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` as the name says fixes the position in the window. If it does not respect vertical scrolling, it of course does not respect horizontal scrolling too. You should use media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
{
    #header
    {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

That's just a hint. You may need to customize or extend this code. But it gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve your desired through `CSS3` `Media Queries` in your css..

Actually you didn't use `Media Queries` that's why your menu is not adjusting according to screen  sizes....

And for how to use CSS3 Media Queries read the mentioned below articles they are really helpful.

[**Media Queries for Standard Devices**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

[**How To Use CSS3 Media Queries To Create a Mobile Version of Your Website**](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: any chance I could just adjust existing css and avoid using media queries?

Comment: @splinterteal, yes, but maybe you do not want to: Change the fixed position to `position: absolute` or even better rewrite it with static position. But with this, you'll lose the fixed menu of course.